# Need reference from Hadith for this Dua. ("Allahumma 'Aghnini Bil 'Ilmi, Wazayyinni Bil Hilmi Wa'akrimna Bi Taqwa Wajammilni Bil Afiyah hadith")

Tags: hadith, dua, reference-request

> اللَّهُمَّ أَغْنِنِي بِالْعِلْمِ وَزَيِّنِّيْ بِالْحِلْمِ
>   وَأَكْرِمْنِيْ بِالتَّقْوٰى وَجَمِّلْنِيْ بِالْعَافِيَةِ

Transliteration:

**Allahumma Aghnini bil 'Ilmi,**
(Oh Allah! Enrich me via Knowledge)

**Wazayyinni bil Hilmi**
(Oh Allah! Adorn me with a sense of humility/gentleness)

**Wa'akrimni bi Taqwa**
(Oh Allah! Deem me noble with Taqwa/Piety)

**Wajammilni bil Afiyah**
(Oh Allah! Beautify me by keeping us in a state of well being/healthy)

A Dua taught by Yasir Qadhi. 
He said this is a Dua of Prophet peace be upon him. He don't give reference.

I need reference of this Dua from Hadith?

Answer (score 3):

This hadith can be found in a couple of sources mostly with disconnected narrator chains or weak narrators:

- You will find it in al-Hilm of [ibn Abi Dunya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abi_al-Dunya) (see [here](http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/display_hbook.php?bk_no=230&pid=128017&hid=3) in Arabic) with a very disconnected chain [Sufyan ibn 'Oyyanah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufyan_ibn_%60Uyaynah) سُفْيَانَ بْنَ عُيَيْنَةَ  is a scholar of the 2nd Century after Hijra so he can't have heard the hadith from our Prophet.

  > اللهم أَغْنِنِي بِالْعِلْمِ وَزَيِّنِّي بِالْحِلْمِ وَكَرِّمْنِي بِالتَّقْوَى وَجَمِّلْنِي بِالْعَافِيَةِ
- There's another very weak isnad (chain) on the authority of 'Ali ibn Abi Talib in tarteeb al-Amali al-khmisiyah ترتيب الأمالي الخميسية of a-Shajari [يحيى بن الحسين الشجري](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%8A%D8%AD%D9%8A%D9%89_%D8%A8%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%8A%D9%86_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B4%D8%AC%D8%B1%D9%8A).

  > اللَّهُمَّ أَغْنِنِي بِالْعِلْمِ، وَزَيِّنِّي بِالْحِلْمِ، وَأَكْرِمْنِي بِالتَّقْوَى، وَحَلِّنِي بِالْعَافِيَةِ
- Ar-Rifa'i al-Qazwini  [الرافعي القزويني](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%A7%D8%B3%D9%85_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%81%D8%B9%D9%8A_%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%82%D8%B2%D9%88%D9%8A%D9%86%D9%8A) has also quoted it in his at-tadween fi akhbar qazwen التدوين في أخبار قزوين, with a better connected chain on the authority of Abudllah ibn 'Omar (apparently this is the chain ibn 'Oyyanah didn't quote as he is part of this chain).

  > اللهم أغنني بِالْعِلْمِ وَزَيِّنِّي بِالْحِلْمِ وَكَرِّمْنِي بِالتَّقْوَى وَجَمِّلْنِي بِالْعَافِيَةِ

On the whole the fact that the hadith was more or less (always) mentioned with the same wording seems a good indication for a possible authenticity. And as weak ahadith in good deeds can be used it doesn't seem a bad or wrong du'a or supplication to use!

I found [this thread](http://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=310375) in Arabic helpful.